# SQL Error [42703]: ERROR: column "percent_population_infected" does not exist

Tags: sql, postgresql, dbeaver

I am having trouble understanding this error that pops up when I try to exclude nulls from my query. Thanks!

```
/* Looking at countries with Highest Infection Rate compared to Population */

SELECT LOCATION, population,
       MAX(total_cases) AS highest_infection_count,
       MAX((total_cases/population))*100 AS percent_population_infected
FROM public.Covid_deaths
WHERE percent_population_infected IS NOT NULL 
GROUP BY LOCATION, population
ORDER BY percent_population_infected DESC;

SQL Error [42703]: ERROR: column "percent_population_infected" does not exist
```

Comment: Alias (percent_population_infected) can't be used in WHERE clause.

Answer (score 0):

The restriction on the percent population infected alias doesn't belong in the `WHERE` clause, it belong in the `HAVING` clause.  Also, I think you just want to assert that a given location has a non zero Covid case count.  Putting all that together:

```sql
SELECT
    LOCATION,
    population,
    MAX(total_cases) AS highest_infection_count,
    MAX(total_cases / population)*100 AS percent_population_infected
FROM public.Covid_deaths
GROUP BY LOCATION, population
HAVING MAX(total_cases) > 0
ORDER BY percent_population_infected DESC;
```